# Excel How can I replace values? TRANSPOSE?

Tags: excel, mapping, transpose

I have several values in my excel sheet that should be replaced with others.
Whenever there's for example "Test 1", I need to have "Application System 1.0". I am going to do an Export with the data, that contains "Test 1". Then I want to have in all my analysises instead of "Test 1" "Application System 1.0". Do you think theres a macro necessary? Or can I insert in every cell where I want to have "Application System 1.0" a formula? I thought of the formula "TRANSPOSE"? So maybe I could do a mapping with the corresponding values? 
The problem is, that I generate the value "Test 1" with another formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($I11,Export!$B:$AW,MATCH($J$1,Export!$B$4:$AW$4,0),0)),"",VLOOKUP($I11,Export!$B:$AW,MATCH($J$1,Export!$B$4:$AW$4,0),0))
```

So when I have a certain number in a cell, the right "Test x" appears in the cell. Though now, I don't want to have "Text x" anymore, but "Application System 1.0". In addition I can't work with the "Application System 1.0" because I get the values "Test x" as I said before, from an export. I don't have any influence on that.

Thank you very much in advance!
Kind regards,
question

Comment: Is the workbook constantly being updated with "Test X" values or just once?  if constantly then a macro replacing test 1 with application system 1.0 makes the most sense.  If this occurs only on import, just do a find and replace all.

Comment: This is very easy with a macro. **Is a macro solution acceptable??**

Answer (score 0):

Prior to exporting the data from Excel, save your file and run this short macro:

```
Sub FixText()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, v, "Test 1") > 0 Then
                r.Value = Replace(v, "Test 1", "Application System 1.0")
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note** that you should save **first** since the macro will replace any formulas that result in text containing "Test 1".

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to think that through and try it in my excel sheet. But thank you for your help!!! @Gary's Student